# Storing data from an HTML table into a 2D array Selenium Java

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I am trying to store data from an HTML table into a 2D array but I can't seem to figure it out. My code currently looks like this.

This is the site where the table is: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

```
@Test
public void checkTable() {

  // Number of Rows in table
  int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='customers']/tbody/tr")).size(); 
  System.out.println("The total number of rows is " + rowCount);

  // Number of Columns in table
  int colCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='customers']/tbody/tr[1]/th")).size();
  System.out.println("The total number of columns is " + colCount);

  // Dynamic X-Path

  String firstX = "//*[@id='customers']/tbody/tr[";
  String secondX = "]/td[";
  String thirdX = "]";

  for(int i=2; i <= rowCount; i++) {
      for(int j=1; j <= colCount; j++) {
          String completeX = firstX + i + secondX + j + thirdX;
          String tableData = driver.findElement(By.xpath(completeX)).getText();
          System.out.println(tableData + "   ");
      }
      System.out.println(" ");
  }
```

And this the current output.

> Alfreds Futterkiste
>   Maria Anders
>   Germany
>
> Centro comercial Moctezuma
>   Francisco Chang
>   Mexico
>
> Ernst Handel
>   Roland Mendel
>   Austria
>
> Island Trading
>   Helen Bennett
>   UK
>
> Laughing Bacchus Winecellars
>   Yoshi Tannamuri
>   Canada
>
> Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti
>   Giovanni Rovelli
>   Italy

I'm trying to get that output to look something like this.

> [[Alfreds Futterkiste, Maria Anders, Germany], [Centro comercial Moctezuma, Francisco Chang, Mexico]]...etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with Selenium. This is based only on logic.
Below is the code you should try. Let me know if it solves your problem.

```
    for(int i=2; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        if(i==2)
        {
            System.out.print("[");
        }

        for(int j=1; j <= colCount; j++) {
            String completeX = firstX + i + secondX + j + thirdX;
            String tableData = driver.findElement(By.xpath(completeX)).getText();

            if (j==1)
            {
            System.out.print("[");
            }

            if (j==colCount)
            {
                System.out.print(tableData);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(tableData + ',');
            }

            if (j==colCount && i!=rowCount)
            {
                System.out.print("],");
            }

            if (j==colCount && i==rowCount)
            {
                System.out.print("]]");
            }       
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hi! It seems to have worked but I actually wanted to store the information inside of an 2D array instead of just console logging what looks like an array. I'm still pretty new to Java. Please help.

Comment: @niko - Do you need brackets '[' and Commas ',' also?

Answer (score 0):

Required output looks like it is generated using Arrays toString() method. So you can use a 1D array and using toString() method to generate it directly without worrying about appending spaces and new lines manually.

1. Now you initalize an 1D array to store result of each row. Create it outside your first loop.

   ```
   String[] rowResults = new String[rowCount];
   ```
2. You can create another 1D array. Place this inside the first loop and outside the second loop.

   ```
   String[] columnResults = new String[coulmCount].
   ```
3. As you start reading the elemnts, add it to the columnResults and once you are done with the inner loop. use the below

   ```
   String columnOutput = Arrays.toString(columnResults);
   rowResults.add(columnOutput);
   ```

   Arrays.toString(arr) for an array "arr"  will give you [ "a", "b", "c" ] format.
4. So once you are done with the execution, just run 
   **Arrays.toString(rowResults)** and you will have the output in required format.

Comment: I see to be getting a compilation error.
`Cannot invoke add(String) on the array type String[]`
 
Happening on the `rowResults.add(columnOutput);`.
Any suggestions?